# Specific data in chart

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, apexcharts

I'm getting this data from backend and need paste it in my Apex Charts chart - https://apexcharts.com/javascript-chart-demos/area-charts/spline/

```
{
    "ADA": {
        "name": "ADA",
        "data": [
            0,
            0,
            "98"
        ]
    },
    "MATIC": {
        "name": "MATIC",
        "data": [
            "127",
            "128",
            "65"
        ]
    },
    "DOT": {
        "name": "DOT",
        "data": [
            0,
            "6",
            "6"
        ]
    }
}
```

Config looks like this with my stupid non iterate solution that works (series it's common array, inside objects with name/data)

```
series: [
        {
          name: props.portfolioGrowthData.data.chart_tokens_data.MATIC.name,
          data: props.portfolioGrowthData.data.chart_tokens_data.MATIC.data.map(
            (x, index) => x
          ),
        },
        {
          name: props.portfolioGrowthData.data.chart_tokens_data.ADA.name,
          data: props.portfolioGrowthData.data.chart_tokens_data.ADA.data.map(
            (x, index) => x
          ),
        },
        {
          name: props.portfolioGrowthData.data.chart_tokens_data.DOT.name,
          data: props.portfolioGrowthData.data.chart_tokens_data.DOT.data.map(
            (x, index) => x
          ),
        },
      ],
```

But this solution it's not what i need because empty tokens displays in chart too and after scale of our app there gonna be a mess of tokens. Looks like i need somehow handle data from backend and iterate objects without static name and data but all my tries are failed... How can i handle it?

Comment: Can you please provide more info? What is an empty token and how does it appear on the chart? Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b4Louf58/) I made putting together parts of your code above - you can adapt it to show your issues.

Comment: Thanks mate you already made my example. Next step it's iterate through series somehow, i mean that series must have one example of iterate object we're going all chart_tokens_data. Coz imagine like 30 tokens going from backend it's obvious that i need iteration now before it's to late

Comment: Right. Well, your `map` function is a good way to iterate through data; if you need to eliminate some bad items you may of course use `filter` and so on. Please let me know if I can help for a more particular issue.

Comment: The problem is that if I start iterating map inside the object, then all the tokens will simply be written into one line of the graph, but I need to iterate from outside the object, somewhere at the level of the main series array

Comment: But what's the problem if all values are displayed in the chart at once? Are they too many, are some values not right and need to be excluded?

Comment: After a while, the number of tokens can become more than 30, and users clearly need to exclude extra lines with 0 data, otherwise a bunch of lines will lie empty at the very bottom and be displayed in the upper markers, confusing a user who does not have such positions

Comment: I'm not sure I understand that exactly; if you think that I, or other people here, can advise you about that, maybe you can put such data that create problems in a fork of that fiddle or a similar one.